# Selection versus Merge Sorting Trouble

Tags: arrays, sorting, computer-science, mergesort, selection-sort

Suppose we have inefficient implementation of swap(a,b)(very costly) function and we are given the choice of four sorting algorithms to choose from, namely:

1. merge-sort
2. selection-sort
3. insertion-sort
4. heap-sort

Which one of the following four will perform the best ?

Now according to me as the swap is a costly operation we need to minimise the number of swaps. so technically the answer should be merge sort as it performs no swapping in its general implementation. But the answer-key suggests that it must be selection-sort instead ? I fail to understand why, please help.

Selection sort first finds the correct index and then swaps which is economical but doesn't merge sort perform better still ?

Comment: A standard merge sort copies elements from one array to another, and never swaps elements. If the question was about minimizing the number of writes, then [cycle sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort) would be the best.

Comment: so the correct answer must be merge sort right ? @rcgldr

Comment: The issue is the term "swaps". As commented before if the issue is that writes are costly, then selection sort would be better than merge sort, but the question doesn't explain why swaps are costly.

Comment: `selection sort` would have worst case n-swaps.  `insertion-sort` would take `n^2` swaps.

Comment: I agree with others.  Why are swaps expensive?  Are they saying that reads are expensive?  Writes are expensive? The standard metrics all assume that comparisons, reads and writes cost the same.  

Under the assumption that the *only* operations you have are comparison and swap, then #2 is O(n) swaps.

Comment: @FrankYellin - merge sort doesn't swap.

Comment: Of course merge sort doesn't swap.  That's my point.  I could rewrite any of the other algorithms so they didn't swap either. My point is that counting swaps and thinking that's a good metric is just a bad idea.  I could see counting comparisons.  I could see counting reads and writes.  But swaps???